# Need help getting an iOS static library working in cordova plugin

Tags: cordova, xcode6, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

Cordova 4.1.2, XCode 6.2

I'm trying to use a 3rd SDK from a 3rd party library for which I have the source, which includes an XCode project of its own. The instructions from the makers say to drag the library .xcodeproj into my workspace. While this works it won't be practical when I'm developing my Cordova plugin.xml since I often destroy and recreate my project's XCode file. I have built the 3rd party SDK which produces a directory of headers, one .a file and a .bundle file.

In my plugin.xml, for the static library,  I have,

```
<source src="src/ios/libKALTURAPlayerSDK.a" framework="true" />
```

According to the plugin spec this should copy the .a file into the project and add it to the link with binaries section. It doesn't appear to do either though. The error I'm getting in my project build for the line,

```
#import <KALTURAPlayerSDK/KPViewController.h>
```

is,

```
..../foo/platforms/ios/foo/Plugins/ca.foo.kaltura/MyFoo.h:2:9: 'KALTURAPlayerSDK/KPViewController.h' file not found
```

KALTURAPlayerSDK is the product name for the .a library. I've tried adding this to the header, library and framework search paths but no luck:

```
$(PROJECT_DIR)/foo/Plugins/ca.foo.kaltura
```

My plugin is copying all the library's header to the plugin folder in my project (should I need to do that?).

Note that as a test, I tried NOT copying any of the framework stuff in my plugin and instead manually dragged the 3rd party (kaltura) library into my project and while that worked, I still couldn't build on the command line with cordova, with the same 'file not found' error as stated above. It builds in XCode but not on the command line. I'd love to get some more insight into the problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

try replace 
import <--KALTURAPlayerSDK/KPViewController.h>
with 
import "KPViewController.h"

also you need to specify your header in plugin.xml

<--source src="src/ios/libKALTURAPlayerSDK.a" framework="true" />

<--header-file src="src/ios/KPViewController.h" />

Comment: Thanks, I'm done that project and we had to give up on that player so I'm no longer able to verify this works but hopefully your answer can help someone else